# net-snmp: Disman Event MIB

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I'm using `net-snmp` and `Disman` Event monitor
with the snmpd.conf

======================================================================

```
monitor -r 1 MachineTooOver .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.196612 > 10

monitor -r 1 MachineTooOver .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2 > 10
```

i found that the first command not working as the second.

( in case `.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.196612` object available )

it's the same for all OID such as.

```
monitor -r 1 MachineOverLoad .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.5 > 10

monitor -r 1 MachineOverLoad .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2 > 10
```

=====================================================================

I need to monitor specific `OID` like `.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.196612`

Does any one know how to do this?.

Comment: Can we assume you followed this tutorial? http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:DisMan_Monitoring

Comment: The flag `-r 1` would seem to poll the Agent every second, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: i followed this tutorial
http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:DisMan_Monitoring
This tutorial told me to trap on "hrProcessorLoad" ( which is .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2 ) 
But i only need to monitor specific OID like .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.196612
Thanks